# emacs set-fontset-font for specific unicode char under windows

Tags: windows, emacs, font-face

I use the following setting to config the font for emacs under windows system

```
(create-fontset-from-fontset-spec
 "-outline-Cousine-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-fontset-Consolas")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-Consolas" 
                  '(#x6d4b . #x6d4c) 
                  "Microsoft YaHei" nil 'prepend)
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :font "fontset-Consolas")
```

After emacs start up, I input that char `#x6d4b` into the emacs buffer, but it turns out to be a square, which means the font setting does not work. I also use `describe-char` to show detail information, and get the following result:

```
             position: 2888 of 4342 (66%), column: 13
            character: 测 (displayed as 测) (codepoint 27979, #o66513, #x6d4b)
    preferred charset: unicode-bmp (Unicode Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000..U+FFFF))
code point in charset: 0x6D4B
               syntax: w    which means: word
             category: .:Base, C:2-byte han, L:Left-to-right (strong), c:Chinese, |:line breakable
          buffer code: #xE6 #xB5 #x8B
            file code: #xE6 #xB5 #x8B (encoded by coding system utf-8-dos)
              display: no font available
```

We can find that the `display` property shows it does not have available font for it, but I indeed give that in the font config.

Could you point out where is the problem? I suppose the set-fontset-font should work even under windows system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you just want to set the default font and a different font for two specific characters, the following works for me:

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Consolas")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x6d4b . #x6d4c)
                  "Microsoft YaHei" nil 'prepend)
```

(`prepend` is unnecessary with Consolas, but may help with your font).

Comment: Could you explain why I need to set the fontset-default, instead of my own fontset-Consolas?

Comment: No idea, I just adapted a snippet from my own config.

Comment: Emacs' mailing lists may be a better place to ask questions like this.